# Log-in redirect in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

i am using Joomla 2.5 inbuilt registration Form .i need to redirect to 2 different pages after different type of user log-in .Can this possible ? .Now my log-in menu redirecting every user to one constant page After successful log-in .

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've created the login with a module, this can't be done unless you edit the Joomla! module itself.
It has a paramter in which you can set one redirect on login and one on logout, but not for 2 different logins!

I hope this helped you!

Kind Regards,
McBurgerKong